Basic Solidity Proxy Pattern Implementation with Foundry
Question
I'm new in web3 development. I've been trying to develop a basic proxy pattern
implementation in Solidity for over a week for testing. I want to create a basic version of either a Transparent Proxy or UUPS Proxy and I'm having difficulty with the implementation. Could anyone help me understand how to properly implement (and test) a proxy pattern using Foundry?
Problem
So far I have tried following both the documentation and multiple tutorials without success. In the proposed solutions there is always some problem with the libraries. Missing solutions, varied signatures, etc etc.
I hope I am not the only one in this situation... I believe that since web3 development is relatively "new," Foundry is definitely under development and being quickly updated, and the Openzeppelin libraries I rely on are constantly being updated and changing often.
Structure / Example
At the moment I would like to develop something with this structure:
2 or 3 implementations of the "logic contract" to simulate the upgrade from a deprecated/error version to the correct one, the Proxy and consequently all the files needed for actual running and testing:

Notes
I know this is not the classic question, but I am really struggling. I am trying to take tests to enrich a potential thesis/research of mine in this area and I have been stuck for too long.
Also, I have noticed a lack of documentation and material in this area. So I hope this question can help multiple less experienced developers like me.
As for the answer I trust the community. I have been using this platform for years now and it has never let me down. It would be nice to have some sort of code + tutorials so as to help newbies as much as possible. For example how to do some testing via the forge command and how to simulate it even on a local blockchain via anvil.
Many thanks in advance
